# Issues on testing In-App-purchase in iOS with Sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I am facing a strange behavior with In-App-Purchase in iOS while testing with sandbox. Few things I observed, Please make your comments where I am wrong.

1. I know sandbox has small time interval for subscriptions like 30 minutes for 6 month subscription. I am using subscription model, when I am trying to purchase same item multiple time, it allows. Is that OK ? As per my understanding, it should allow only once to purchase and in subsequent call, it should say "Already purchased".
2. When I am restoring my previous purchase. Storekit is calling updateTransations with large number of previous transactions. Don't know why it is returning these large amount like 100, 200 ,245, 360, 650 seems like Random in every restore.

Please make your comments. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
OP

Comment: PLEASE HELP...I AM STILL WAITING FOR REPLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear All,

```
           As I did not get reply on this thread. We have done testing an make the app live, app is working fine. Here are my comments that might be helpful to others.
```

1. When testing with sandbox, since time interval is not same as live app. You get 5 minutes for 3 month subscription and so on, so once your subscription expire your subscription will be renewed. If you will make one more payment request if subscription is live, you will get popup for already purchased.
2. Apple sends a large number of transactions, we need to add condition by our own, so that we will identify the current transaction and will process that only, rest will be ignored.

Hope this will help you all.

Thanks,
Om

Comment: I think the reason you got no replies was because of the tag you used. More accurate tags will garner a greater number of replies.